# Finding lines of optimization in multidimensional surfaces

Tags: math, mathematical-optimization, calculus

I want to optimize a function for a multivariate surface given a range of values for one variable.

For example, take the equation for the following quadratic surface:

z = x + x^2 + xy + y^2 + y.

How would I find values of y that maximize z given all possible values of x? The result should be a line along the surface that maximizes z at every value of x.

I have found a lot of resources online that explain how to find maxima and minima, as well as saddle points, but I am not sure if that approach will be relevant - the slope of the surface along that line will usually not be 0, so I don't think it makes sense to use derivatives here.

I am new to calculus and mathematical optimization. I would be thrilled if someone would point me to a resource that could help me out with this problem

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you only want to consider (x,y) points in a certain area. Can you clarify what that area is? Is it a set of lines? A rectangle?

Comment: Thanks Joni! I want to define a line that maximizes (or minimizes) z along every possible value of x. So, given x, what are the values of y that maximize z?

Comment: To illustrate, let's say I know that x = 6. What value of y given that value would give me the highest value of z?

Comment: For the z = f(x,y) given as an example? No value of y will give the greatest value of z: if you choose one value for y, I can always find another value that will give a greater value of z. Maybe your example should be a function that actually has a local or global maximum? In that case, `z = f(6, z)` is a simple real function on y and you can find its extrema at the points where the derivative df/dy vanishes.

Comment: Let's say that z = f(6,y). What values of y would maximize/minimize z, given that x=6? It will not give the most extreme value possible on the surface, but the most extreme value given that x = 6.

Comment: If you take the surface defined by z = f(x,y) and slice it with the vertical plane x=6, the intersection of the surface and the plane is a curve - in this case a parabola. The lowest point on that parabola is at a point where dz/dy = x + 2y + 1 = 0, which gives you y = -(x+1)/2. For the plane x=6, the lowest point of the parabola is obtained at y = -7/2.

Comment: Got it. Thanks Joni!